# App Crashes on ParallelRenderQueue thread with Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiwebview

I am facing a crash with the following log. Basically I am trying to add an Image to a web view through camera. 
The flow is as follows: 
1. I take a picture through camera using Image Picker controller, save it into PhotosAlbum and get the image data.
2. Then I upload that image to the server, get the related data to that image.
3. Then I call a JS function to insert the URL received of the image in the web view.

After repeating the steps 1-3 for a couple of times, I get a crash on this particular thread.

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000040

Triggered by Thread:  16    
Thread 16 name:  Dispatch queue: CA::CG::ParallelRenderQueue 
Thread 16 Crashed:

```
0   AGXMetalG5                      0x0000000107f2a3c4 0x107f20000 + 41924
1   AGXMetalG5                      0x0000000107f689b0 0x107f20000 + 297392
2   AGXMetalG5                      0x0000000107f694b8 0x107f20000 + 300216
3   AGXMetalG5                      0x0000000107f2c308 0x107f20000 + 49928
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189b34cdc CA::OGL::MetalContext::start_render_encoder(CA::OGL::Surface*) + 268
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a2b07c CA::OGL::Context::prepare_destination_() + 32
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189b39920 CA::OGL::MetalContext::draw_elements(CA::OGL::PrimitiveMode, unsigned int, unsigned short const*, CA::OGL::Vertex const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, CA::OGL::ClipPlane const*) + 184
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a00ccc CA::OGL::Context::ClippedArray::next_rect(CA::Bounds&) + 340
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189abd468 CA::OGL::emit_one_part_rect(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::RectState const&, float const*, float const*, unsigned int) + 800
9   QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a2a3ec CA::OGL::fill_rect_tex(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::RectState const&, float const*) + 188
10  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a29fa0 CA::OGL::ContentsGeometry::fill_and_unbind(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::Image*, CA::OGL::TextureFilter, float) const + 976
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189aed41c CA::CG::fill_image(CA::CG::Renderer&, CGImage*, CA::Rect const&, CA::Mat2<double> const&, bool, bool, CGInterpolationQuality, CA::Bounds const*) + 2200
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a02298 CA::CG::DrawImage::draw_image(CA::CG::Renderer&, bool) const + 100
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001899fe574 CA::CG::DrawOp::render(CA::CG::Renderer&) const + 1280
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189af3b3c CA::CG::Queue::parallel_render_callback(void*) + 320
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a96d770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a978cbc _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 72
17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001899fcbc4 CA::CG::Queue::render_callback(void*) + 176
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a96d770 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a97975c _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a971274 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a97b62c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019a97b34c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ab81478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
```